# Creating game menu with classes

Tags: python

I am supposed to create the menu for a text-game with classes, but I don't really know how to "connect" the different types of classes that I will create. For example, 2 menus that I have to create are "Start menu" (where you choose to start a new match, load an existing game or exit) and "Game menu" (where you can select play, save match and exit).

I already have an idea of creating each class, but, as I just said, I don't know how to "connect" these 2 menus, I don't know how to advance from the start menu to the game menu. How can I do this?
The idea that I have is something like this:

```py
class Start_Menu:

    def selected_option(option):
        while option != "1" and option != "2":
            option = input()

    def load_game():
        ...
    def exit_game():
        ...
...

class Game_Menu:

    def play():
        ...
    def load_game():
        ...
    def exit_game():
        ...


``
```

Comment: What kind of human interface will your game have, textual or graphical? You need to decide that first because it will likely affect how to do what you're asking about.

Comment: Textual interface

Answer (score 0):

As @martineau said in a comment, a State Machine is a good approach.
Given your broad example, you could create lets say:

```
class StartMenu(object):
    def load_game(self, game):
    def exit_game(self, game):

class GameMenu(object):
    def load_game(self, game):
    def exit_game(self, game):

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, menu=StartMenu()): # lets say that it starts with StartMenu
        self.menu = menu

    def load_game(self):
        return self.menu.load_game(self)

    def save_game(self):
        return self.menu.save_game(self)

    def set_game_menu(self):
        self.menu = GameMenu()
```

Doing it this way, you can implement different behavior for each of the Menu's that has access to the current game state.

Comment: Thanks! this idea seems good. However, I'm still a bit confused on how could I make it so the game continues running until the user picks the "exit game" option (This will be the only way to exit the game). For example, what should I use to start running the code and start with StartMenu? Should I create something like game = Game() (an instance of this class) and work with that? Sorry about the question being a bit too basic but this is my first time trying to make a game menu with classes